# STM32F405: WWDG interrupt occurs right after WWDG enabling

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, interrupts, watchdog

I've faced the problem with WWDG on STM32F405 (the same problem described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245965/stm32f4-wwdg-interrupt-fires-as-soon-as-its-enabled/662331#662331), but with no no solution):
After enabling WWDG interrupt occurs immediately, despite the fact, that counter is far from the value 0x3F and I update counter before it is enabled. My initialization:

```
LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_WWDG);
LL_WWDG_SetPrescaler(WWDG, LL_WWDG_PRESCALER_8);
LL_WWDG_SetWindow(WWDG, 0x7e);

LL_WWDG_EnableIT_EWKUP(WWDG);
LL_WWDG_ClearFlag_EWKUP(WWDG);
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(WWDG_IRQn);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(WWDG_IRQn);

LL_WWDG_SetCounter(WWDG, 0x7d);
LL_WWDG_Enable(WWDG);
```

I deliberately set counter value less than window value to have possibility update timer any time.
So does anyone know why interrupt occurs immediately after enabling?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out the problem: I thought that if I set counter value less than window value, I will have opportunity to reload counter any time, but with this setup EWKUP flag was not cleared. So I put window value equal to counter and problem disappeared.